# Use Limit and Offset in Doctrine2 query

Tags: symfony, pagination, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to do the pagination, but there is an error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected end of string, got 'limit'

I'm not quite sure if this is the right syntax (and logic) to make my query:

```php
public function getFriendsFromTo ($user, $limit, $offset)
{
     return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT f FROM EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend f WHERE f.user='.$user.' limit '.$limit. 'offset' .$offset)
        ->getResult();
}
```

Friends and users are related manyToOne and oneToMany, so in the friends table there is a field - user_id.

This is in my controller:

```php
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$id = $user->getId();

$friends = $user->getFriends();
$result = count($friends)
$FR_PER_PAGE = 7;
$pages = $result/$FR_PER_PAGE;

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$friends = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
         ->getFriendsFromTo($id, $FR_PER_PAGE, $page*$FR_PER_PAGE);
```

I know that it's stupid and even wrong (especially the third parameter to be `$page*$FR_PER_PAGE`), but I just wanted to try if the query works, and it didn't.

Comment: What did you mean it didn't work? get any errors? You should also be using `setParameter("user", $user)` instead of inserting it directly into the DQL. Also, it would be nice to see your entity definitions. EDIT: just seen the edit. There should be a space appended to 'offset'

Comment: Yes, I get an error - it's in the beggining of the question.

Comment: This bundle may be of interest to you: http://knpbundles.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: Thank you :) but I prefer to do it without a bundle in order to understand it better.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Nope. Use:

```
  return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('...')
        ->setMaxResults(5)
        ->setFirstResult(10)
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: But how to set from where the results should start?

Comment: Be careful if you use JOIN in your DQL. It will not perform as expected: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

Comment: is there a simple way, how to know if there are more enities left in the DB? i mean, if the result of this query contains the last entity in the database.

Answer (score 36):

```
$towary = $this->getDoctrine()
   ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Towar') 
   ->findBy(array(),array(),10,($current-1)*$numItemsPerPage);
```

Comment: I found this more useful since I wanted to use the findBy() function

Comment: and what is `$current` please?

Comment: @Josiah current page

Answer (score 25):

You can use `findBy` 3rd and 4th parameters of method of doctrine repository, which are `limit` and `offset`.

Here is the method definition:

```php
findBy(
    array        $criteria,
    array        $orderBy  = null, 
    integer|null $limit    = null,
    integer|null $offset   = null
)
```

Source: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine2.6, stumbled upon this old post and tried the DQL way but it did not fit for purpose. So if you want to avoid using DQL because you already have Entities mapped and joined together, you can do paging using *matching & Criteria*

```
$criteria = Criteria::create()
            ->setMaxResults($limit ? $limit : null)
            ->setFirstResult($offset ? $offset : null)
$result = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')
            ->matching($criteria)->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

$query->getSingleResult();